# Unable to connect to the Azure IOT MQTT using org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3

Tags: java

I am using "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3" to connect to my java code to azure IOT but while connection MQTT exception has been raised.

Steps:

1) Created MQTT client.

2) Created SSL Factory.

3) Finally connecting to Azure IOT.

But while connect exception has been raised as:

```
Inside AzureCommunicator::connect, Could not connect due to an MqttException!

MqttException (0) - java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.net.Socket cannot be cast to class javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (java.net.Socket and javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.net.Socket cannot be cast to class javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (java.net.Socket and javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
```

Code Snippet:

```
        // Connect our client.
        System.out.println("Inside AzureCommunicator::connect, Trying to connect...");
        try
        {
            //client.connect(options);
            client.connect(options).waitForCompletion();
        }
        catch (MqttException e1)
        {
            System.out.println("Inside AzureCommunicator::connect, Could not connect due to an MqttException!\n");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I found, Paho MQTT need to update in order to accept the custom socket type.